# TypeError in python code from ebook. Don't understand where problem is

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's the code:

```
# Feature Selection with RFE
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
# load data
filename = 'pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv'
names = ['preg', 'plas', 'pres', 'skin', 'test', 'mass', 'pedi', 'age', 'class']
dataframe = read_csv(filename, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:8]
Y = array[:,8]
# feature extraction
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
rfe = RFE(model, 3)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
print("Num Features: %d" % fit.n_features_)
print("Selected Features: %s" % fit.support_)
print("Feature Ranking: %s" % fit.ranking_)code here`    # Feature Selection with RFE
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

error is apparently in this part of the code:

```
rfe = RFE(model,3)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

[RFE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE) only appears to take 2 *positional* arguments (one of them being the implicit argument passed to `RFE.__init__`). The 3 should be one of the optional keyword-only arguments instead of an additional positional argument.

```
ref = RFE(model, n_features_to_select=3)
```

(I'm not sure what ebook you are referring to, but perhaps it's out-of-date and `RFE` used to take more optional positional arguments?

The [last change to the signature `RFE.__init__`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/c3817500cc5ff4997df72de2742d536d516a6c8c#diff-703a0379f13db62c4c9272ba713d6444e3d49e6a7531e8a5fb0eaae55e686592L160) deprecated most of the positional arguments in favor of keyword-only arguments. I don't know enough about the library to say for sure, but it looks like `n_features_to_select` is a renaming of the previous `threshold` argument.)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I love this site! That worked. It is very frustrating trying to learn Python and ML/DL using ebooks and online courses. A lot of these courses have outdated code and not a lot of support sometimes which makes it all the harder for new coders who are old like me.